# r data.table groupby join in pyspark 1.6

Tags: r, join, pyspark, data.table

I have the following datatables (R code):

```
accounts <- fread("ACC_ID |     DATE   | RATIO | VALUE
                   1      | 2017-12-31 | 2.00  | 8
                   2      | 2017-12-31 | 2.00  | 12
                   3      | 2017-12-31 | 6.00  | 20
                   4      | 2017-12-31 | 1.00  | 5      ", sep='|')

timeline <- fread("    DATE  
                    2017-12-31
                    2018-12-31
                    2019-12-31
                    2020-12-31", sep="|")
```

In R, I know I can join on `DATE`, by `ACC_ID`, `RATIO` and `VALUE`:

```
accounts[, .SD[timeline, on='DATE'], by=c('ACC_ID', 'RATIO', 'VALUE')]
```

This way, I can "project" `ACC_ID`, `RATIO` and `VALUE` values over `timeline` dates, getting the following data table:

```
 ACC_ID | RATIO | VALUE  |   DATE
    1   |    2  |    8   |2017-12-31
    2   |    2  |   12   |2017-12-31
    3   |    6  |   20   |2017-12-31
    4   |    1  |    5   |2017-12-31
    1   |    2  |    8   |2018-12-31
    2   |    2  |   12   |2018-12-31
    3   |    6  |   20   |2018-12-31
    4   |    1  |    5   |2018-12-31
    1   |    2  |    8   |2019-12-31
    2   |    2  |   12   |2019-12-31
    3   |    6  |   20   |2019-12-31
    4   |    1  |    5   |2019-12-31
    1   |    2  |    8   |2020-12-31
    2   |    2  |   12   |2020-12-31
    3   |    6  |   20   |2020-12-31
    4   |    1  |    5   |2020-12-31
```

I've been trying hard to find something similar with PySpark, but I've not been able to. What should be the appropriate way to solve this?

Thanks very much for your time. I greatly appreciate any help you can give me, this one is important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do a cross join?

```
spark.sql('''
select ACC_ID, RATIO, VALUE, timeline.DATE
from accounts, timeline
''')
```

Comment: That's it! Dunno why I thought it wasn't a cross join, I was almost there... Thanks very much :D

Comment: @sneaky_lobster it might help to think in terms of the expected number of rows in your output. If you expect `nrow(x) * nrow(i)` rows, that's a cross-join.